# Почему долго загружается Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Недавно переустановил **Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria**, но стала долгая загрузка, почти полторы минуты, предыдущая версия грузилась быстро. Покопался в интернете, сделал некоторые манипуляции, загрузка по времени осталась прежней, а вот выключение практически мгновенной.
Выкладываю время загрузки

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 1.462s (firmware) + 8.010s (loader) + 37.850s (kernel) + 7.205s (userspace) = 54.529s 
graphical.target reached after 7.194s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame
9.935s mintupdate-automation-upgrade.service
3.439s gpu-manager.service
2.460s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1.536s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.131s networkd-dispatcher.service
986ms  dev-sda2.device
928ms  fwupd-refresh.service
...
```

Comment: «37.850s (kernel)» — а что в это время в логах / на экране?

Comment: набор всякого, за всем не уследишь

Comment: Наверное придётся уследить. Ну или понадеяться, что это всякое смогло попасть в логи, и полистать `journalctl -b`

Comment: Что именно надо выложить из этого вывода? Потому, что очень длинное всё

Comment: а что показывает `systemd-analyze blame` и `systemd-analyze critical-chain` ?

Comment: systemd-analyze blame: 9.935s mintupdate-automation-upgrade.service
3.439s gpu-manager.service
2.460s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1.536s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.131s networkd-dispatcher.service
 986ms dev-sda2.device
 928ms fwupd-refresh.service
Дальше не ставлю потому, что там маленькое время

Comment: если автообновление для вас некритично(можно делать это вручную) то отключите сервисы `mintupdate-automation-upgrade` и `apt-daily-upgrade`.

Comment: @user501383 а какой смысл смотреть blame и critical-chain, если основное время загрузки занимает не userspace?

Comment: Пробовал отключить всё в автозагрузке, загружалось за 56 секуд

Comment: @andreymal _обновление_ такая штука которая зависит от многих параметров и если здесь мы видим 10 секунд то в другой раз может занять и минуту а то и больше.

Comment: @vlad63 кстати если в файл `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` в параметр `HOOKS` добавить `systemd` то вывод `systemd-analyze` станет немного подробнее. `HOOKS=(... systemd ... )` после чего нужно пересобрать `sudo mkinitcpio -P`

Comment: @user501383 боюсь, найти mkinitcpio в linux mint будет проблематично)

Comment: А может это всё потому, что у меня вместо DVD привода стоит второй SSD диск?

Comment: @Vlad63 это наоборот должно потенциально ускорять загрузку

Comment: Тогда что может замедлять загрузку? На строй версии у меня грузилось очень быстро

Comment: Моё предложение полистать `journalctl -b` всё ещё в силе (не выкладывать, а полистать и подумать)

Comment: @andreymal и то верно, ну тогда нужно сделать поправку на ubuntu/mint https://askubuntu.com/a/1210481

Comment: @vlad63 так вы пробовали отключить сервисы `mintupdate-automation-upgrade` и `apt-daily-upgrad` ?

Comment: Решил проблему! Грузится за 26 сек. Добавил в файл vi /etc/default/grub  -  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet rootfstype=ext4  libahci.ignore_sss=1 raid=noautodetect selinux=0 plymouth.enable=0 lpj=12053560"